# Move every second row to row above in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe in this shape:

```
    A     B     C    D     E 
  213-1  XL   NaN    NaN    NaN
  21   22.0   12   232.0  101.32
  23-0    L   NaN    NaN    NaN
  12     23   12   232.2    NaN
  31-0   LS   NaN    NaN    NaN
  70     70   23     NaN   21.22
```

I would like to move every second row of that dataframe to the row above so that there are only combined rows left as seen in the expected result:

```
     ID   Name     A     B    C     D     E
   213-1    XL    21   22.0  12  232.0  101.32
   23-0      L    12     23  12  232.2     NaN
   31-0     LS    70     70  23    NaN   21.22
```

Is it possible to do with Pandas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use `concat`:

```
new_df = pd.concat((df.iloc[::2, :2].reset_index(drop=True), 
                    df.iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)),
                   axis=1)

# rename
new_df.columns = ['ID', 'Name'] + new_df.columns[2:].to_list()
```

Output:

```
      ID Name   A     B     C      D       E
0  213-1   XL  21  22.0  12.0  232.0  101.32
1   23-0    L  12    23  12.0  232.2     NaN
2   31-0   LS  70    70  23.0    NaN   21.22
```

Answer (score 6):

`concat` on `df.iloc[::2]` and `df.iloc[1::2]`:

```
df1= (df.iloc[::2].dropna(axis=1).reset_index(drop=True))
df2 = (df.iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True))

print (pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True,axis=1))

#
       0   1   2     3     4      5       6
0  213-1  XL  21  22.0  12.0  232.0  101.32
1   23-0   L  12    23  12.0  232.2     NaN
2   31-0  LS  70    70  23.0    NaN   21.22
```

Answer (score 4):

```
master_df = df[~df['C'].isna()].reset_index(drop=True)
master_df[['ID','Name']] = pd.DataFrame(df[df['C'].isna()][['A','B']].reset_index(drop=True), index=master_df.index)
```

**Output**

```
##print(master_df[['ID','Name','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']])


     ID Name   A     B     C      D       E
0  213-1   XL  21  22.0  12.0  232.0  101.32
1   23-0    L  12    23  12.0  232.2     NaN
2   31-0   LS  70    70  23.0    NaN   21.22
```